# Have multiple buttons with same attributes (class, type, value, etc) that can "point out" their parent DIV when called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having some trouble figuring this out. I want to make it so I can place a button in a number of different `DIV`s but have all the info for the button be the same (class, type, value, etc), this is because its an **edit** button for the DIV so its just something that is automatically included with any new DIV that is created and my server-side app will generate these buttons automatically. So the issue is how to get the ID of the parent DIV, and I am having some trouble with this as it seems to always default to DIV `upd1` even when I click the button contained within `upd2`, I've been searching on this but everything I have found so far hasn't led me out of this issue.

```
<div id="upd1">
    <input id= "button" class="button" type="submit" value="Click to edit this Panel" /> 
</div>

<div id="upd2">
    <input id= "button"  class="button" type="submit" value="Click to edit this Panel" /> 
</div>

then I have:

$("#button").click(function() {
    dividediting = $("#button").closest("div[id^='upd']").attr("id");
    alert(dividediting);
});
```

Comment: Your `"#button"` should be ".button"`, btw.

Comment: my mistake, I had id= "button"  in my actual script, I just over-edited it when I put it into the post here.. I changed it

Comment: That's alright, I've done that before too.

Comment: you can't use the same id on two objects.

Comment: yeah, I just mean it would be nicer if it gave an error so it makes it more obvious :) since it can be a time waster if you don't catch it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function() { 
   var dividediting = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   alert(dividediting); 
});
```

You **cannot** have two items with the same `id` - you have to be using a class not the same `id` on each button.

Comment: oh, can't believe I was missing that, I was using "this" earlier for something else, that makes complete sense now..will try that

Comment: @Nick interesting, I amended (I usually use attr("id") but get blasted for not using standard JS functions).

Comment: @Graphain - You would need `.parent()[0].id` or `.parent().get(0).id` for that, which would be valid as well (it *must* have *some* parent).

Comment: @Rick, you can't use the same id on two objects

Comment: @Nick ah thanks, I just turned it back to attr("id") like I had originally.

Comment: awesome, the $(this) fixed it.. (I also changed it to use the class instead of id) thanks.. also, it seems you can have 2 ids but it just will take the first (meaning the HTML page still renders but obviously its of no use to have 2)

Comment: @Rick Glad to hear. Yeah it compensates and renders, but it's invalid and JS won't work with it. It's like if I leave tags open, the browser still has a guess at making them work but you're dealing with "guess" behaviour, not "reliable" behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) for your buttons instead, like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    dividediting = $(this).closest("div[id^='upd']").attr("id");
    alert(dividediting);
});
```

`#button` is an [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) that searches for an `id="button"` instead of a `class="button"` like you want.  Also you want `$(this)` inside the handler, so you're getting the closest `<div>` of the *clicked* element, not the first matched `.button` element.

Comment: The `.class` won't fix the fact the OP is using `#button` in the internal selector.

Comment: You need .class in the second line as well, `$(".button")`

Comment: @Graphain - Oops missed the internal, fixed, @phoffer actually you want `$(this)` instead in there.

Comment: Ya you're right. I got stuck on that little `#` and forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, why are you using `$("#button")` i didn't see any id="button" in your DOM, secondly, you can use this

```
var dividediting = $(".button").parent().attr("id");
alert(dividediting);
```

Comment: my mistake, I had id= "button"  in my actual script, I just over-edited it when I put it into the post here.. I changed it

Comment: no the OP cannot, that will give the first button's parent, not the clicked one's.

Comment: ahh yes, because there are 2 `.button` classes in your DOM so the first `.button` will be taken, but if you are calling it inside an event you can use `this` instead of `.button` selector just like Graphain's example.